# Error con Jasper Report y Itexpdf 5

Tags: jasper-reports, itext

Tengo un problema al generar un reporte con *jasper report* me sale la siguiente excepción `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException` entiendo que no encuentra la clase **com.lowagie** ya que la excluí de jaspert por que esta deprecada

```
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
<artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
<version>6.17.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Me parece extraño ya que en tomcat si funciona pero en JBOSS me da este error.

Espero me puedan ayudar a solucionarlo.

Saludos.

Comment: Mas que obsoleta, hubo un cambio de licencia y un fork pero sigue activa (artifactId `openpdf`). Tal vez la versión sea vieja, pero si es la que requiere JR... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Eso no lo sabia pero lo malo es que el dependency check detecta esa dependencia con vulnerabilidades y no la puedo usar por ello también la excluí